# How can I create one DataFrame from multiple files with different format in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know that I can use either `spark.read.csv()` or `spark.read.json()` to load CSV files or JSON files as one DataFrame, but what if my source files are actually in different format, for example, some of my original data are in CSV files but some others are in JSON files? Is it possible for me to create one DataFrame that contains data from both my CSV and JSON files?
Probably I should load them separately and use the JOIN operation on DataFrames, or I should firstly convert all my JSON data into the CSV and load them with a single `spark.read.csv()`, but I'd like to listen to your suggestion since I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to create one dataframe by reading from different file formats but you would have to read them separately and then do union on them to create the final dataframes.

You would have to identify the below stuffs before you do this:

1. do you have csv files and json files in the same folder or different folders. If they are in different folders you can read the entire directory and if they are in same folder you can read them using wild card character approach to read all the files of specific type.

   spark.read.csv("*.csv")

   spark.read.json("*.json")
2. you will also have to make sure that the schema that gets generated by reading the csv file and the json files is same . if the schemas are different you could perform some transformations on it and bring them to the same schema so that you can perform union on it.
3. if you are doing union on two dataframes created by reading different file format types, you need to make sure that the column names and datatypes are same in both dataframes . If the columns order is same in both dataframe you can use union() function if not then unionByName().

Comment: It's really helpful! I believe this is exactly what I want. Thank you so much!